# How to set and get images for face detection in android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, firefox

We are doing a small project about face Recognition systems. Here I have a problem storing the data and retrieving it. How can I store the real face of a person to firebase and retrieve it while Face recognition?

Code: https://github.com/estebanuri/face_recognition/blob/master/android/app/src/main/java/org/tensorflow/lite/examples/detection/DetectorActivity.java

Anyone has a solution please Reply!

Thank you!!